# I have two installs of Firefox after trying to update

Tags: apt, firefox, snap

Tried to update Firefox with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Now, I have two installs: version 59 in `/snap/bin/firefox` and version 60 in `/usr/bin/firefox`.

I'm worried using the `autoremove` command to remove version 59 will mess with version 60.  What to do?

Also, what was the better way to do this?  Should I have just removed Firefox and reinstalled the newest version?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed two versions of Firefox - one via `apt-get install` and the other from a [snap package](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro). You can verify that by running

```
snap list
```

The output should contain Firefox (snap version). You can launch it by

```
snap run firefox
```

Also

```
apt-cache policy firefox | grep Installed
```

should list the usual apt-version.

It's completely fine to have both them in your system, they will coexist without interacting with each other. `autoremove` will almost certainly won't remove any of them (except possibly for some other unrelated reason).

If you wish you can remove the snap version by running

```
snap remove firefox
```